# Error when using pander on a data.table created with data.table::dcast

Tags: r, data.table, pander, dcast

this is more a question of interest, as I found a work-around, although I don't find it pretty.

When I updated the pander package (to 0.6.1) an error started to occure whenever I try to to use pander() on a data.table in wide format that was constructed from a data.table (package version 1.10.4-3 or older) in long format using data.table::dcast():

> Error in data.table::setattr(x, "row.names", row.names.dt) : 
>     row names must be 'character' or 'integer', not 'double'

I tried to remove any row names, but to no avail.  After some research, I found out that with reshape2::dcast there is no error, but reshape2::dcast transforms the data.table in a data.frame, which isn't something I want. Of course I could transform the data.frame back into a data.table.

Here is some sample code that produces the error for me:

```
library(pander)
library(data.table)

dt.long <- data.table(time=c(1, 1, 2, 2), T=c("c", "t", "c", "t"), count=c(10, 15, 15, 20))
pander(dt.long) # this works fine

dt.wide <- dcast(dt.long, time~T, value.var = "count")
row.names(dt.wide) <- NULL # doesn't help
row.names(dt.wide) <- c() # doesn't help either
pander(dt.wide) # produces error

# work-around
library(reshape2)
dt.wide <- dcast(dt.long, time~T, value.var = "count")
pander(dt.wide) # works fine
class(dt.wide) # but this is a data.frame
dt.wide <- data.table(dt.wide) # now it is a data.table again
```

Is there a simple way to keep the data as data.table and use pander as it worked before?
I use R version 3.3.2, in case this matters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the additional attributes that creates the problem.  Set the 'sorted' `attr` to 'NULL' and it should work

```
dt.wide <- dcast(dt.long, time~T, value.var = "count")
attr(dt.wide, "sorted") <- NULL
```

Or use `setattr`

```
setattr(dt.wide, 'sorted', NULL)
pander(dt.wide)
#----------------
# time   c    t  
#------ ---- ----
#  1     10   15 

#  2     15   20 
#----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious workaround to coerce `dt.wide` to data.frame in the call to `pander()` (`dt.wide` remains unchanged)

```
pander(as.data.frame(dt.wide))
```

> ```
> ----------------
>  time   c    t  
> ------ ---- ----
>   1     10   15 
>
>   2     15   20 
> ----------------
> ```

the `data.table` method of `pander()` has a `keys.as.row.names` parameter (see `?pander.data.table`). This parameter is `TRUE` by default.

So, another workaround is to set this parameter to `FALSE`:

```
pander(dt.wide, keys.as.row.names = FALSE)
```

> ```
> ----------------
>  time   c    t  
> ------ ---- ----
>   1     10   15 
>
>   2     15   20 
> ----------------
> ```

However, I believe there is a bug in `pander()` as `dt.wide` is not keyed. It just has the `sorted` attribute set to `time`:

```
str(dt.wide)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ time: num  1 2
>  $ c   : num  10 15
>  $ t   : num  15 20
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "time"
> ```

Note that if column `time` is defined as *integer*, `pander(dt.wide)` doesn't throw an error but is omitting the `time` column from the result.
(See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/315)).